# Java - Create a web service from an available class

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I had a java project and after lots of research I managed to convert it to a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. Now I want to add a new Web Service to it. I have already developed a class. I want to convert it to a standard Web service so I can call it from my silverlight application. Here's my current class:

```
public class MyWebService 
{
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod
    public String ProcessQuery(@WebParam(name="query") String q)
    {
        MessageContext messageContext = context.getMessageContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) messageContext.get(SOAPMessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        // now you can get anything you want from the request
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String address = "http://127.0.0.1:8023/_WebServiceDemo";
        Endpoint.publish(address, new MyWebService());
        new DocumentServer();
        System.out.println("Listening: " + address);
    }
}
```

How can I do it in Eclipse? Please post a link to a tutorial or a quick step by step guide. I'm a .Net developer and I'm very new to Java.

Thank you.

PS: So basically I want to publish this service in a standard way rather than calling this main function and using Endpoint.publish() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Bottom-Up_Java_Web_Service) has a tutorial using the Web Tools Platform to do just what you are looking for.  It requires WTP and Tomcat, if you don't have those already available to Eclipse.  It starts with an unannotated class and finishes with a WSDL and test client.  It allows you to view generated SOAP messages.

To create, it instructs you to select the file you want to convert into a web service and run `File -> New -> Other... -> Web Services -> Web Service`.  Then you click `Next`, move the slider to the `Start Service` position, and client to `Test Client`.  You select `Monitor the Web Service` and then click `Finish`.  Then you can play with your Test Client and see your generated WSDL.

Note that the above paragraph is a summary of the tutorial, which you can find in full at the provided link.

Comment: I did all of the steps but when I try to access the methods (either in my silverlight app or Service Explorer) I get this: org.apache.axis.InternalException: java.lang.Exception: Couldn't find a matching Java operation for WSDD operation "processQuery" (1 args)

Comment: @Alireza - did you follow my summary or the actual tutorial?

Comment: i notice you mention the exception is processQuery, but the method is defined as ProcessQuery with a captital P. Have you attempted to change these to match?

Comment: I don't know either to laugh or cry! Thanks to Sean, I investigated the problem with the names. After a few builds and tries, I found out that because by convnntion the java method names don't start with a capital letter, changing the capital letter to a small character would solve the problem!!!! OMG!!! Thanks both you guys. You helped me a lot. The only problem I have now is how to run this service on other machines and the real server which I'm going to ask in another thread. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, if anyone wants to try a better solution for creating a web service, Thrift seems as the best option. I have created a tutorial on [my blog](http://www.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/)