# Cannot load file in a java Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have a Web service developed in Java. One of my services doesn't work. After investigating the problem I found out that [probably] when I try to load a file, I get an exception so it throws a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. I tried running this piece of code and every time I got False.

```
java.io.File f = new java.io.File("svncache.collection");
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

I tried copying the file in the Tomcat's root (*\webapps\ROOT*) but it didn't work. I ran this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

and copied the file to the folder returned by this function. After this, the function returned `true` so I guess this is the root folder I should work with. But when I run the service again, I get the same exception. I run this service on Windows 7 x64 and Eclipse for Java EE Helios.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Thanks.

Edit:
I should mention that this was originally a Java project (not a Web application). I had to use it as a Web Service. The first suggestion was to use Endpoint.publish. Here:

[Add a web service to a already available Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595028/add-a-web-service-to-a-already-available-java-project)

After conversion [and a little edit] it ran perfectly without any problems. But I needed to log user activity and as suggested I converted the project to a Dynamic Web project and created a new Web service:
[Java - Rich logging in web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625739/java-rich-logging-in-web-services)
and 
[Java - Create a web service from an available class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635408/java-create-a-web-service-from-an-available-class)

So basically I'm running in circles. Using Endpoint.publish doesn't support logging, using Web Services won't allow me to load files and the original Java project cannot be used as a Web Service for my Silverlight application.

Please help me. I'm so frustrated. Thanks.
PS: Sorry I had to change the question to clarify my problem and the title to match that.

Comment: Where do you **expect** the file `svncache.collection` to exist? You specify a relative file name, which is usually a risky thing to do. Is this a file contained inside of your webapp?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't care where the file is. I just want to load that file. Even when I use "C:\\temp\\svncache.collection" it cannot load it. As for the second part, I don't completely understand your question. This is a very crucial file for my service and I have to load it in order to respond to requests.

Comment: Well you **should** care where it is, after all you want to read it. If it's part of your webapp, then you should not use a `File` at all, but use `ServletContext.getResource[AsStream]` or `Class.getResource[AsStream]` to load it (depending on whether it's in somewhere in your webapp or in a `.jar`/in the `/WEB-INF/classes` directory).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that test in your webapp, not just from within an ordinary Java application. If it works in your webapp, you have definitely misdiagnosed the problem. If it doesn't... well, you can fix that.

Comment: All of these results are in the Web Service. The original Java project runs flawlessly. Please read the question again. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: I think the UAC is preventing my web service from accessing the file. I ran this code and it returned false. `System.out.println(f.renameTo(f2));` If you know how to give the service admin priviliges, please let me know. I'll have to wait a few hours before I can restart my windows (to disable UAC and test whether my theory is true) but I'll be nice to do it without the need to disable UAC. THanks

Comment: I disabled UAC but problem is still there.